# Install ROS dependencies from apt?

Tags: ros, rosdep, apt, bloom-release, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAICT, using apt packages is a bit of an all-or-nothing deal— you can either:

1. install everything from apt, letting apt resolve dependencies, or
2. install everything from a rosinstall, letting [rosinstall_generator](http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall_generator) resolve them.

The obvious thing for a mature package is to install the latest release from apt, and then use rosinstall to create an overlay which you can hack on. But this is not a great solution for packages which are not yet released, perhaps because they are still experimental, in early development, etc.

Am I mistaken here, or is there some ROS invocation which can scan the package.xml dependencies of a workspace, and then spit out (or execute) the necessary apt-get install command? Or is the solution to just create apt releases from the earliest possible point?

---

For future travellers, here are some cut and paste friendly versions of the incantation given below by @tfoote:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=groovy -y
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=hydro -y
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=indigo -y
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=jade -y
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75241/install-ros-dependencies-from-apt?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2013-08-28

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohbotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/23169/rohbotics/) on 2016-07-25**:
For kinetic:
`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=kinetic -y`

**Comment by [danielchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/52349/danielchen/) on 2020-03-09**:
For melodic: `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=melodic -y`

**Comment by [pra-dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/58760/pra-dan/) on 2020-10-28**:
For noetic `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=noetic -y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a catkin WORKSPACE with some sources checked out and you want all the rosdep dependencies installed use the following

```
rosdep install --from-paths WORKSPACE --ignore-src --rosdistro=ROSDISTRO
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-28**:
You can add `--yes` to confirm all actions automatically, and you can add `--simulate` to see what rosdep would do before it commits to installing the things.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-08-28**:
Unless I'm mistaken, rosdep is still only handling "system" dependencies, not dependencies on the apt packages which correspond to ROS packages. Does rosdep in fact cover both scenarios?

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-08-28**:
When I attempt the suggested invocation, I get a list of which "packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies"

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-28**:
rosdep will resolve all system dependencies defined in the rosdep database and any released ros packages into their apt-get names, e.g. `catkin` => `ros-hydro-catkin`

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-08-28**:
Excellent, thanks—that works perfectly.

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-08-28**:
@William: Is this only valid for catkin packages? For rosbuild package with unknown dependencies rosdep install returns an error: "ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies: test_package: Missing resource ackermann_msgs".

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-28**:
`rosdep install` can also take rosbuild packages and stacks which are on your RPP. See `rosdep help`

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-08-29**:
Filed a ticket for rosdep here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/268 .